# How do I "link" or read input using my Bison parser?

Tags: parsing, bison, flex-lexer

I know that a parser reads the tokens produced by a lexer. I have a working lexer created with Flex++ that reads in a text file and outputs the tokens to standard output. In terms of parser, I currently have a parse.y file and a parse.tab.c file that is generated after running

> bison parse.y

These are currently the only files I have and I just have question on whether I need another .cc/.cpp file that allows my parser to take in input. I was thinking I can have my lexer output into a seperate .txt file and then my parser can take that .txt file as input. What approaches should I take?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Bison parsers get their input by calling a function (by default `yylex`) that returns the next token of input.  It will call it repeatedly to get all the token of input until it returns a 0 or EOF token.

Flex produces a lexer function called `yylex`, which nicely matches up with what bison expects.  So all you have to do is have your lexer rules `return` tokens (rather than outputting them to stdout) and link together the bison parser and flex lexer and they'll work together.

The hardest part is getting flex and bison to agree on token codes.  The usual way to do that is to give bison the `-d` option which causes it to output a `.tab.h` file with the token definitions it is using.  You can then `#include` that in your lexer (inside a `%{`..`%}` block in the first section) and you can then use the same names for tokens in your lexer code.

Any introduction to yacc or bison text you can find will give examples of doing this.

Comment: My lexer rules already returns tokens and my flex file has a main function that calls yylex and prints to standard output based on the token returned. Does bison parsers automatically call yylex or should I also have a main function in my .y file?

Comment: You need a `main` function that calls `yyparse` -- the main entry point for the parser.  `yyparse` will automatically call `yylex` as it needs tokens.

Comment: I guess my main problem is understanding the actual command that links everything together. I should call 'g++ -o parse parse.tab.c lex.yy.cc' and the 'yyparse' in 'parse.tab.c' will call the 'yylex' in 'lex.yy.cc'? For my lexer the command line commands I use would be 'g++ -o lexer lex.yy.cc' and then select the input file using './lexer test.txt' with test.txt as the argv[1]. Would I have to change which file reads in the argv[1] for my parser?